# Reading csv in r - numbers like "general"

Tags: r

First, I am new on R.
My csv has some numbers considered like "general" so I can't do the math with data. Is there any solution for this?
I have tried `data >- as.numeric ( as.character(data))` but I failed.

```
data <- read.csv(file="TC.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")
data[ data == "?" ] <- NA
for(i in 1:ncol(data)) {
  data[is.na(data[,i]), i] <- mean(data[,i], na.rm = TRUE)
}
```

I get this message:

*In mean.default(results) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA*

I think the problem is related to numbers like on yellow cell.

Sample input:

[image: sample]

[image]

Comment: Share some more information like a sample csv and the code you use to read it.

Comment: Ok, thanks for attention

Comment: This seems a real issue, I have been able to reproduce it.

Comment: This issue looks good now, from SO point of view, and if you care then please accept or upvote the answer you got.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that error message because you are applying the `mean` function to a `list`, when it operates on `numeric` types.

In R, the usual way of dealing with multi-dimensional data is not to loop over it, but to use one of the various `apply` functions, which perform an operation on one dimension of your data.  Here you are looking for the column mean, which you get by:

**TC.csv**

```
a_0,a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4
3030.93,1,1,1,1
3095.78,2,2,2,2
2932.61,3,3,?,3
3032.24,4,4,4,4
2946.25,5,5,5,5
3058.88,6,?,6,6
```

**get_mean.R**

```
data <- read.csv(file="TC.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",", na.strings="?")

# apply( data, dimension, function, function_args )
col_means <- apply( data, 2, mean, na.rm=1 )
```

[Apply Functions Over Array Margins](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/apply.html)

[Apply a Function over a List or Vector](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/lapply.html)

Comment: Could you assess @DylenMDale's answer (since I lack R experience) and give him an upvote for his efforts?

Comment: col_means is returning NA. And I need replace NA with the mean of each column.

Comment: Just add `na.rm=1` as an extra argument to apply.  I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Works for me....perhaps you could add the code to generate your data to the question, instead of an image....where there are no NAs....

Comment: Not working even when I use a simple csv like the one I atached now                 data <- as.data.frame(read.csv(file="TC2.csv", header=TRUE, sep=","))

data[ data == "?" ] <- NA

col_means <- apply( data, 2, mean, na.rm=1 )

Comment: Try now...it works for me with your data, I justed added the `na.strings="?"` bit to the `read.csv` call to get rid of the `?` values.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to loop over the data set to remove rows. Also, I don't believe the highlighted rows are the root of the problem. To make it easier, I would convert the data to a data frame.

```
    data <- as.data.frame(read.csv(file="TC.csv", header=TRUE, sep=","))
```

To remove the '?' character, you should be able to run the code below. I think it is easier to run the code below instead of converting it to NA and then dropping it.

```
    data <- data[!grepl('?',data$Column),]
    mean(TC$Column)
    summary(TC)
```

In summary, you should convert it to a data frame, replace/drop the rows that have values that aren't numeric, and then perform your summary stats.

Comment: Hi. I cant drop it the ?.  I have ? and NAs.  After turns ? into NA, I need replace them by the mean of each column. Is there a easy way to do this?